# web2py post login redirect

Tags: redirect, authentication, web2py

I had a working login form for my web2py app.

I don't know what I changed but after login is performed the app returns me the invalid function default/user msg.

I was using auth.settings.controller="user"  to be redirected to the right controler. Now it doesn't work.

App should go back to the page it came from. only with logged in user

Right after solving this i am installing myself a SVN but until then. 
I really don't know what to do

I am alo using auth.navbar()

my auth in view is {{='auth' in globals() and
                        auth.navbar(separators=(' ',' | ',''))}}

my user controler user.py is

def user():
        form = auth()
      return dict(form=form)

and my user.py model is

if (request.controller=='user' or request.controller=='school'  or request.controller=='timetable' and request.cookies.has_key('mycookie')):
    response.generic_patterns = ['*'] if request.is_local else []
    database = request.cookies['mycookie'].value
    baza = DAL('postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/' + database, migrate=True)
    from gluon.tools import Mail
    auth = Auth(baza)

```
auth.settings.logout_next=URL('school','index?school=' + database)


auth.settings.registration_requires_approval = True
#auth.settings.reset_password_requires_verification = True
#auth.settings.login_after_registration = False
auth.settings.register_onaccept=lambda form: mail.send(to=['vid.ogris@algit.si'],
      subject='web2py registration',
      # If reply_to is omitted, then mail.settings.sender is used
      reply_to='us@example.com',
      message='Kreiral se je nov uporabnik, ki ga je potrebno potrditi') 

auth.settings.expiration = 3600
auth.define_tables()

mail=Mail()
auth.settings.mailer=mail
mail.settings.server='smtp.gmail.com:587'
mail.settings.sender='xxx@gmail.com'
mail.settings.login='xxx@gmail.com:xxx'

#auth.settings.registration_requires_verification = True

auth.messages.registration_pending = u'Registracija je v postopku odobritve. Ko bo vaš račun potrjen boste prejeli e-mail.'
auth.messages.invalid_login = 'Nepravilno geslo'
auth.messages.invalid_user = 'Uporabnik ne obstaja'



auth.settings.controller="user"



## if you need to use OpenID, Facebook, MySpace, Twitter, Linkedin, etc.
## register with janrain.com, write your domain:api_key in private/janrain.key
from gluon.contrib.login_methods.rpx_account import use_janrain
use_janrain(auth,filename='private/janrain.key')
```

Comment: Can you show your Auth setup code as well as your user controller code? When you go to the login page, what is the _next parameter in the query string?

Comment: also if I click on retrieve password i get an email with wrong addres. It tries to put me on portalov_iurnik/default/user/reset_password/1346840165-f35f1af2-f1fb-45c1-afff-fb822c2cf35d where It should redirect me to portalov_iurnik/user/user/reset_password/1346840165-f35f1af2-f1fb-45c1-afff-fb822c2cf35d. It is getting to default all the time.
and if I enter url of the page I should get to it redirect me to /portal_iurnik/default/user/etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes comments in html are not only comments :) I removed a line containing auth.register(), even though I though it was commented, and now it works

Comment: If you have something like `<!-- {{=auth.register()}} -->`, the Python code will still be run by the template engine. HTML comments are for commenting HTML. To comment Python code, you have to use Python comments: `{{#=auth.register()}}`. This allows the templates to generate HTML that includes comments.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `auth.settings.controller` doesn't work (the book needs to be updated). Instead, you have to do:

```
auth = Auth(baza, controller='user')
```

Also, instead of:

```
URL('school','index?school=' + database)
```

you should do:

```
URL('school','index', vars=dict(schools=database))
```

Comment: ok that helps a little (I don't get the invalid function error) but why i am after hitting the login button redirected to /user/user/profile?? instead to a view where I was before?

Comment: Sounds like you're calling `auth.register()` somewhere. If you call that function after a user is already logged in, it will redirect to `auth.settings.logged_url`, which defaults to the profile URL. In your code, first check if the user is already logged in before calling `auth.register()`.